# Turn off sending to sender with MulticastSocket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, multicast, multicastsocket

I'm sending data with MulticastSocket in Java. Messages have structure "username: data" and so far I've been doing:

```
if (!message.startsWith(this.nick + ":"))
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Is there any way not to send the message to sender at all? This way I just ignore this message, but waste efficiency.

Comment: Disable loopback.

Comment: @user207421 I cannot do this, since I'm running multiple clients on the same machine through loopback and no client would receive such message.